# What Is the Location for Each Zoni?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-a-crack-in-time

I'm trying to locate each of the Zoni, in part for the Zoni Collector trophy.  Some of these are in optional areas so I'm looking for a sort of checklist.

If certain story-related or skill requirements must be met, can they be listed with each location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IGN has a nice [full walkthrough](http://faqs.ign.com/articles/104/1046790p1.html) which includes all the Zoni locations. To get there quickly, search the page for `#ZONI`. The second one will start the Zoni walkthrough.

If you're having a problem finding a specific Zoni, you can always head to YouTube and search for something like `Ratchet and Clank Crack in Time Zone <Planet>` and you'll almost always find a video walkthrough for finding the Zoni on that planet. I personally use videos more often because the text walkthroughs aren't always very detailed and can sometimes be confusing figuring out where they're starting from.

Answer (score 0):

When you win the fourth battle of the 2nd tournament if the battle ship thing, you will actually unlock a treasure detector, and after you have unlocked this on the map there will be all the treasure (Gold Bolts, Zoni, RYNO V schematics, constructo mods) pinned on the map(in there correct location) so you will easily be able to find them. The treasure detector also increases the amount of ,,Treasure,, listed on the planets and zone lists.

Comment: What’s with the random commas? If you want to edit your post you can [click here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/378370/edit).